# Unable to replace different matches with a single replace in Vim

Tags: vim, replace

I tried the following code unsuccessfully

```
:%s/{car,beatles}/mas/g
```

How can I replace **car** and **beatles** with mas in Vim with a single command?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work:

```
:%s/\(car\|beatles\)/mas/g
```